# Loop through datarow and update cell

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the following code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    //cell cannot contain any of the following characters: :\/?*[]'                       
                }
```

I do not know the names of the column before hand or I could do something like:

```
    if (row["Name"].ToString() == "SomeName").
```

What I like to do is if any of the cells contains any of the characters :/?*[]' I like to replace that with an empty string.

Comment: You can try with Contains(). Something like this:   if (row.ToString().Contains(@":\/?*[]'"))
                {
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `Regex.Replace` with `:|\\/|\\?|\\*|\\[|\\]|'"` to replace characters to empty string.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(":|\\/|\\?|\\*|\\[|\\]|'");
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (object item in row.ItemArray) 
    {
        var result = regex.Replace(item.ToString(), string.Empty);
    }
}
```

[c# sample](http://rextester.com/NDRC44572)

```
Regex regex = new Regex(":|\\/|\\?|\\*|\\[|\\]|'");
var result = regex.Replace("2:76000?0178'12?0[0]8", string.Empty);
```

**Result**

```
276000017812008
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    // Loop through the cell values
    foreach (object item in row.ItemArray) 
    {
       // Get the cell value
       string cellValue = item.ToString();
       // Remove unwanted characters
       cellValue = cellValue.Replace(":","");
       cellValue = cellValue.Replace("/","");
       cellValue = cellValue.Replace("?","");
       cellValue = cellValue.Replace("*","");
       cellValue = cellValue.Replace("[","");
       cellValue = cellValue.Replace("]","");
       cellValue = cellValue.Replace("'","");
    {
}
```

This may not be the best way but it should work if you are in a hurry